# http POST request to jax-rs web service

Tags: java, web-services, rest, grails, jax-rs

I have a `jax-rs` web service in `grails` framework that respond to PUT requests and consumes/produces xml or json but when i try to PUT a xml to web service via chrome's advanced rest plugin it gives error `415 Unsupported Media Type`.

I want to know how  can i PUT a xml into web service?
Note: I am using application/xml as content type
My code  for web service is:

```
     @Path('/api/interface')
        @Consumes(['application/xml','application/json'])
        @Produces(['application/xml','application/json'])
        class InterfaceResource {

        @POST
            @Path("xmldata")
            String  getInterfaceRepresentationXML(def xml) {
                //play with xml and render xml result
            }
        }
```

So the link would be `x.x.x.x/api/interface/xmldata`  and that does not accept XML file .
Please help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

did you set the content-type to `application/xml` instead of the default `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` ?

or, do you have another endpoint in your application with the following URL Template:

```
x.x.x.x/api/interface/{param}
```

which also consumes `PUT` requests but does not accept `application/xml` content type ? (I'm not sure which resource method would be selected by the JAX-RS implementation, though)

Comment: hey i have used application/xml and i have updated the whole service code and there is no other such resource

Comment: why do you submit a PUT request if your method is annotated with @POST ?

Answer (score 0):

*On the server side*

@Consumes and @Produces directives should be tied to the method.
Also, verify your required http method is @POST (PUT method is rarely used in such cases, but you are free to use PUT if you really want it this way).

```
@POST
@Path("xmldata")
@Consumes('application/xml')
@Produces('application/xml')
String getInterfaceRepresentationXML(def xml) {
    //play with xml and render xml result
}
```

*On the client side*

Be sure your client use the correct http method (POST or PUT, as declared on sever side).
Providing xml data in the http post content is not sufficient, you must also inform the server on what kind of data you are giving to it. You must provide the content-type in the http headers.

In chrome's advanced rest client, specify in the headers:

```
Content-Type: application/xml
```

Comment: `@Consumes` and `@Produces` annotation can be set on the Java type, and will be used for every method unless overridden at the method level.